# Convert Object to Array [Java]?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have an `Object (Object o)` which when I call `o.toString()` it prints:

```
{data-ved=0EMIuCBcoAA, data-pid=23, href=https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm, class=gb_P}
```

As you can see there seems to be an array of Strings in this object. Is there a way to directly convert the object to a String[]?

The expected result would be a String[] containing something like:

```
data-ved=0EMIuCBcoAA
data-pid=23
href=https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm
class=gb_P
```

Currently, I'm using `Regex` to extract the parts of the String I need (as array).

*Is there a better way to do this?*

If it matters, the object is being returned from a `JavaScript Executor` in `Selenium`.

Comment: That representation doesn't necessarily mean a string array. The data itself looks a lot like JSON so I guess what you actually have inside that object is a map. Don't you have any additional information beside it being an `Object` (which doesn't mean much in Java since almost everything is an object)? According to the [JavaDoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)  you probably get a `WebElement` so I'd check the class via `instanceof` and cast accordingly.

Comment: @Thomas Not really. The return type is of type Object. The method signature is Object executeScript(String arg0, Object... arg1); All I can see is that the return type is an Object. And I don't think JS executor returns a WebElement (as you need to cast Driver to JS Executor) but I might be wrong.

Comment: See my edited comment: you very likely get a `WebElement` (you could check that by calling `o instanceof WebElement`). If it isn't you should be able to  get the class of that object via `o.getClass()` then use `instanceof` and casts as appropriate.

Comment: "I don't think JS executor returns a WebElement (as you need to cast Driver to JS Executor)" - if the driver class implements `JavascriptExecutor` then a cast shouldn't be necessary (and otherwise you should get an exception anyways). Additionally since the interface states it would return `WebElement` for any HTML element (as per documtentation) any implementation of the interface should do that.

Comment: "(you could check that by calling o instanceof WebElement)" - I tried this & it was not an instance of WebElement

Comment: As @Thomas said, your example looks like the `toString()` of a Map — it is definitely _not_ an array which looks like `[string1, string 2, etc]`. You will never get an Array out of `toString()` so you either must have some _other_ method you can call, or you can parse the toString output into an array yourself.

Comment: So what did you get then? What does `o.getClass()` return?

Comment: @Thomas `getClass()` returns `com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap`

Comment: There you go, you get a `Map` and thus you should be able to get what you want by casting to `Map` or probably `Map<String, Object>` and calling `et("data-ved")` etc., i.e. something like `if( o instanceof Map) { return ((Map)o).get("data-ved"); }`.

Comment: @Thomas Brilliant it works. I would accept it as the answer if I could.

Comment: Well, that's the least problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in the comment trail the object that is returned seems to be a `Map` (and probably a `Map<String, Object>` or `Map<String, String>`). Thus you could do the following:

```
if( o instanceof Map ) {
  Map map = (Map)o; //If you know the generic type you could use Map<String, Object> etc. instead
  String dataVed = (String)map.get("data-ved");
  ...
}
```

As you can see casting the value is needed as well since there's no generic type provided for the map and thus all you know is that keys and values are objects of any class.

If you know what generic type should be used you could improve that, especially if the value type is `String`. Unfortunateley due to type erasure you can't get that type at runtime so the only way to get to know what to expect would be some documentation.